# Issue of German visa for job, simultaneously with Amsterdam visa for study

Tags: visas, germany, netherlands, study, working-visas

I resident of India , got admission in study course at Amsterdam, simultaneously got appointment letter from company at German. Since time is limited and I wish to know that can I apply for visa simultaneously for both countries. If there any boundation to apply one by one. As I'm not sure which will materialised.

Answer (score 1):

You need two different visas for two different purposes. So you can either apply for a work visa in Germany, or one to study in Amsterdam.

For each, you will need to submit your passport; and each require a different set of requirements in terms of paperwork.  Therefore, you cannot apply for both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to any number of visas at a time. However, most countries will require your passport while processing a visa. This would make it difficult to simultaneously apply to two visas, but you could apply for a German visa now, and then one for the Netherlands next.